# Mule SharePoint connector

Tags: sharepoint, mule

I am trying to deploy mule project and below error occured

by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'sharepoint:dws-create-folder'

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/> 
<sharepoint:config name="MS_Sharepoint" 
                   username="${Sharepoint.Username}" 
                   password="${Sharepoint.Password}" 
                   siteUrl="${Sharepoint.SiteUrl}" 
                   domain="${Sharepoint.DomainName}" 
                   doc:name="Microsoft SharePoint: Legacy Connection" 
                   scope="${Sharepoint.scope}" 
                   stsUrl="${Sharepoint.StsUrl}" 
                   disableCnCheck="true"/>
```

Flow :

```
<flow name="create-folder"> 
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/createfolder" doc:name="HTTP"/> 
    <sharepoint:dws-create-folder config-ref="MS_Sharepoint" 
                                  doc:name="Microsoft SharePoint" 
                                  url="/SharedDocuments/Test"/> 
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> 
</flow>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML ?

Comment: i am unable to post complete xml as its too long.

Comment: <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
     <sharepoint:config
     name="MS_Sharepoint" 
     username="${Sharepoint.Username}"
     password="${Sharepoint.Password}"
     siteUrl="${Sharepoint.SiteUrl}"
     domain="${Sharepoint.DomainName}"
     doc:name="Microsoft SharePoint: Legacy Connection"
     scope="${Sharepoint.scope}"
     stsUrl="${Sharepoint.StsUrl}"
     disableCnCheck="true"/>

Comment: <flow name="create-folder">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/createfolder" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <sharepoint:dws-create-folder config-ref="MS_Sharepoint" doc:name="Microsoft SharePoint" url="/SharedDocuments/Test"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>

Comment: Can you please edit your questions and add these XML blocks as code blocks. I assume you imporrted the sharepoint namespace ? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35332785/edit

Comment: Yes i have imported namespace but i am unable to place complete file